# MySQL Syntax Error When Uploading Image

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, syntax

I'm having issue uploading a BLOB into my MySQL database and get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄ' at line 1
```

I know the error is resulting in the image's file contents but I can't figure out what's wrong with the syntax. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Here's the PHP:

```
    $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

// If there's no file selected when button is pressed, echo out and tell the user to select an image to upload
if (!isset($file))
    echo "<p>Please select an image to upload.</p>";
else {
    //mysql escape string
    $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    //and here
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $imagesize = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
}

// Checks that the file being uploaded is an image, i.e. has a size attribute with height & width dimensions
if ($imagesize == FALSE)
    echo "<p>Please upload only an image file such as .jpg or .png.</p>";
else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO design (id, caption, image) VALUES ('', '$image_name', '$image')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result)
        echo "<p>Something went wrong.</p>" . mysql_error();
    else {
        echo "<p>Thank you for submitting your design.</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of stuffing images in database you have to store them in a filesystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the image file contents has an apostrophe in it.  That's not that surprising.  You need to properly escape the input (and all inputs for that matter).

```
$image = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

---

Instead of using `ext/mysql`, you should use properly parameterized queries with mysqli or PDO.  Then you don't have to escape explicitly.

Comment: Only problem with your answer is that you're still using the mysql_* functions which have been depreciated and I would recommend not using them.

Comment: @Diemuzi I do in the second paragraph

Comment: Thanks! I even commented in my code to add `mysql_real_escape_string` to both those variables! I'm an idiot.